# Why isn't CrossAxisAlignment.end working here?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget

In a `ListView` I am returning either a left aligned widget or a right aligned widget. The left alignment is working fine, but the right alignment isn't for the username. Why is this?

```
Widget myRegularMessageWidget(String uid, String username, int timestamp, String text) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
            ),
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 1, 
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(username,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16)
                ),
                subtitle: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text(text),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }


  Widget otherUserRegularMessageWidget(String uid, String username, int timestamp, String text) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
          ),
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.75, 
            child: ListTile(
              leading: const CircleAvatar(
                child: FlutterLogo(),
              ),
              title: Text(username,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16)),
              subtitle: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(text),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Image of the output (for some reason the normal way to add a pic isn't working):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create two separate functions for showing your message and other user messages just wrap Username, Message widget with a column and add a condition for showing left/right.

[image: Output]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  int? selectedIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final isSelected = index == selectedIndex;
              return FractionallySizedBox(
                     widthFactor: 1, // set width of listtile
                     child: ListTile(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedIndex = isSelected ? null : index;
                        });
                      },
                      leading: index % 2 == 0
                          ? const CircleAvatar(
                              child: FlutterLogo(),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                      title: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: index % 2 != 0
                            ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                            : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Username ${index + 1}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      trailing: index % 2 != 0
                          ? const CircleAvatar(
                              child: FlutterLogo(),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                      subtitle: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: index % 2 != 0
                            ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                            : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('This is message ${index + 1}'),
                          Visibility(
                            visible:
                                isSelected, // used for show/hide date when message is clicked on
                            child: Text(
                              DateTime.now().toString(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** You need to replace `index % 2` this condition with your uid or username like `if (uid == 'myId')` then `CrossAxisAlignment.end` or else `CrossAxisAlignment.start`. Everywhere in the above snippet for getting the desire output.

Comment: You need to replace this `leading: index % 2 == 0` with `leading: uid != currentUID` and this `trailing: index % 2 != 0` with `trailing: uid == currentUID`.

Comment: Yup I realized I didn't switch it everywhere haha. It's working! I am going to post another question on this same code, hopefully you can help me out with that one as well!